# Slang metaphorical animal names used to describe people

Tags: words, slang

Does Japanese slang use animal names to describe people's personalities in the same way English does?  If so, what are some common ones?

For example, in English, men can often be called "dogs" or "cats"; sometimes I hear "ape".

> - All men are **dogs**!　→　can mean "disgusting", sexually selfish, etc.
> - That guy's a real cool **cat**.　→　a (smooth) guy; relaxed
> - What a bunch of **apes**!　→　Large, slow, possibly bumbling, rough, rude (野暮)

There are several common terms for women too: "birds" (usually British English only), "minx", "dogs", "foxes"/"foxy".

> - Do you fancy that **bird**?　→　a fine (young) woman
> - You wily **minx**!　→　a sly girl; possibly very flirtatious
> - OK, so my girlfriend's a **dog**.　→　an ugly woman
> - What a total **fox**!　→　attrictive, beautiful, sexy (which is ironic since foxes and dogs are closely related)

Does Japanese slang describe people with certain animals?  The only one that comes to mind is `豚児`, but that seems like antiquated "peasant" 謙譲語 more than slang.  If they don't use animals, is there some other "system" that is used?

Comment: What's the point in answering in Japanese?

Comment: @oldergod Sometimes it's easier to get the meaning in Japanese across when the comment doesn't have to be translated into English... perhaps? ^^;

Comment: @oldergod, the point is that many students of Japanese appreciate the chance to study from Chocolate's comments.

Comment: does 雌豚 count? Technically bitch is also animal in nature!

Comment: Sorry... I was just lazy... (and also because my English writing skills are poor...><)

Comment: @Chocolate, please do not hesitate to write in Japanese.

Comment: 猿でも分かるお返事を楽しみに待ちます

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are some, but I get the impression that such usage is more common in English.

Here are some examples:

- ～の犬 /  spy of ...
- [走狗]{そうく} / literal: hunting dog, but it means a lowly man that does just what he was told.
- 馬鹿 / fool: while [the origin of the word appears more complex](http://gogen-allguide.com/ha/baka.html), I think this one still counts.
- 猿芝居 / a poor lie
- [雌豚]{めすぶた} / insult to a woman, bitch.

In addition, because there are such plethora of English insult words using animal names, some of them effectively became Japanese, as in チキン野郎 (a coward), 豚野郎, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  Don't know why I didn't think of `馬鹿`.

Comment: Added rubi as you suggest.